# Customize Stripe error messages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe and "custom forms" from the API. The following code is throwing errors if something is wrong, in English, but I want to translate some of the error messages into Norwegian to make it more user friendly for my customers. For example "invalid_expiry_year" and "invalid_expiry_month" which is currently in English.

**Is it possible to achieve and if so, how?**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_2iA9ERjj5lVuUgvOS9W5fNtV');
    $(function() {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');
      $form.submit(function(event) {
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
        $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

        // Request a token from Stripe:
        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from being submitted:
        return false;
      });
    });
    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {


    function stripeHandler( status, response ){
      if ( response.error && response.error.type == 'card_error' ){
        $( '.errors' ).text( errorMessages[ response.error.code ] );
      }

      else {
        // do other stuff (and handle api/request errors)
      }
    }
      // Grab the form:
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) { // Problem

        // Show the errors on the form:
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

      } else { // Token was created!

        // Get the token ID:
        var token = response.id;

        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

        // Submit the form:
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for you to set up the stripe form in a different language than English, but only for a few other [languages Stripe supports](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#supported-languages). For a custom integration, you will have to pass `locale: 'auto'` when calling `StripeCheckout.configure()` so the language will be detected automatically. There’s more info in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).

However, since Norwegian isn't supported yet, what I am suggesting is mapping the response codes and providing your own translations for the errors.

```
var errorMessages = {
  incorrect_number: "The card number is incorrect.",
  ....
};
```

You can find a complete list with all error codes [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors)